# Check datetime.now is in between two datetime objects or not

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
A = 2018-09-27T12:00:00.000-0500
B = 2018-09-27T19:00:00.000-0500

C = 2018-10-17T15:27:57.604399-0500
```

I would like to check if `C` datetime object is between `A` and `B` or not. Do I have to manipulate objects with `strftime` to get desired result?

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid syntax. Give a [mcve] of what you've actually tried, and be specific about the problem with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use dateutil to easily parse your dates:

```
from dateutil import parser

parser.parse(A) < parser.parse(C) < parser.parse(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the datetime library you can compare timestamps with > and <.